# Rspec model methods return nil when created by let

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, rgeo

Ok, so this may seem like a total newbie ask, but when I create an instance of my model with `let`, for some reason all of the getter methods on it return nil. Here's my example:

**Model:**

```ruby
class Parcel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend UUIDHelper

  serialize :address, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore

  self.rgeo_factory_generator = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory srid: 3785

  attr_accessible :address, :area_poly, :id, :lonlat, :municipal_id
end
```

**Spec:**

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'
require 'street_address'

describe Parcel do
  let(:geo_factory) { RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 3785)}
  let(:point1) {geo_factory.point(-72.9229165, 41.3096987)}
  let(:point2) {geo_factory.point(-72.9229169, 41.3096987)}
  let(:point3) {geo_factory.point(-72.9229169, 41.3096983)}
  let(:point4) {geo_factory.point(-72.9229165, 41.3096983)}
  let(:line_string) {geo_factory.line_string([point1,point2,point3,point4])}
  let(:polygon) {geo_factory.polygon(line_string)}
  let(:parcel) { Parcel.create(
      municipal_id: 'abc123',
      area_poly: polygon,
      #lonlat: polygon.centroid,
      address: StreetAddress::US.parse('55 Whitney Ave New Haven, CT 06510').as_json
  )}

  it "#municipal_id should not be nil" do
    parcel.municipal_id.nil? should_not be_true
  end
end
```

(the #longlat attribute is commented out because calling the `.centroid` method on a spherically defined polygon in RGeo is a no-no. Getting the right projection, while on my list of to-dos, is not relevant to this question)
And the spec fails like so:

```
expected: non-true value
  got: #<Parcel id: nil, municipal_id: nil, address: {}, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, area_poly: nil, lonlat: nil>
```

FWIW, here's the Rspec log:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (7.2ms)  SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='parcels'
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (4.2ms)  INSERT INTO "parcels" ("address", "area_poly", "created_at", "id", "lonlat",     "municipal_id", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)  [["address", "\"number\"=>\"55\",\"street\"=>\"Whitney\",\"street_type\"=>\"Ave\",\"unit\"=>NULL,\"unit_prefix\"=>NULL,\"suffix\"=>NULL,\"prefix\"=>NULL,\"city\"=>\"New Haven\",\"state\"=>\"CT\",\"postal_code\"=>\"06510\",\"postal_code_ext\"=>NULL"], ["area_poly", #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPolygonImpl:0x80b773e0 "POLYGON ((-72.9229165 41.3096987, -72.9229169 41.3096987, -72.9229169 41.3096983, -72.9229165 41.3096983, -72.9229165 41.3096987))">], ["created_at", Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:59:51 UTC +00:00], ["id", nil], ["lonlat", nil], ["municipal_id", "abc123"], ["updated_at", Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:59:51 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

For reference, I can successfully run `Parcel.create` in a Rails console, and get instance variables to return non-nil values

I'm running rails 3.2, using postgres 9.3 with postgis 2, and heavily relying on activerecord-postgis-adaptor, RGeo, activerecord-postgres-hstore, among other gems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @UriAgassi Rspec log is showing *ROLLBACK*. There is other issue... may be validation..

Comment: @ArupRakshit _ROLLBACK_ may be related to a `DatabaseCleaner` policy, I don't think a-priori that this is part of the problem.

Comment: Once you got the answer, ping me please.. I wanted to see this mysterious error's reason also :-)

Comment: @PeterAlvin 's answer worked. The ROLLBACK is likely a DatabaseCleaner policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a period. `should_not` is intended to be sent to the object whose value you are checking, as in:

```
parcel.municipal_id.nil?.should_not be_true
```

Because it's monkey patched on all objects, though, you were invoking it on RSpec's `subject` and passing the result (a `Proc`) as a block to `nil?`, which is ignoring it. The error message reflects that the object being evaluated is the subject `Parcel` instance.

As an aside, note that the current and preferred syntax for this in RSpec is:

```
expect(parcel.municipal_id.nil?).to_not be_truthy  # be_true was renamed to be_truthy in RSpec 3
```

or if you really want to only check for a value of `true`:

```
expect(parcel.municipal_id.nil?).to_not be(true)
```

or if you want more compactness:

```
expect(parcel.municipal_id).to_not be_nil
```

or if you prefer the Shakespearean feel:

```
expect(parcel.municipal_id).to be
```

or if you want to take advantage of `its`, which was factored out into a separate gem as of RSpec 3, then you can replace the entire `it` call with:

```
its(:municipal_id) { should_not be_nil }
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the new RSpec syntax.